# Generic procedure to perform SCD in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, scd

I have 2 tables in mssql server.I can perform scd through custom insert/update/delete and also through Merge statement.

- [Awesome Merge](http://chrisjarrintaylor.co.uk/2012/07/03/ssis-scd-vs-merge-statement-performance-comparison/)

I want to know that is there any generic procedure that could  server the purpose. we just pass it 2 tables and it should porform the SCD. any option in SQL server 2008?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't and there can't be a generic one suitable for no matter what tables you pass to it. For several reasons:

- How do you know which SCD type? (Okay, could be another parameter, but...)
- How do you know which column should be historicized and which should be overwritten?
- How do you determine which column is the business key, the surrogate key, the expiration column and so on?
- To specify the columns in an update statement you must write dynamic sql, which is possible, but the above point comes into play

Not a reason why it's not possible but also consider: For a proper `UPSERT` one usually works with temporary tables, the `MERGE` statement sucks for SCDs except in special cases. That is because you can't use a `MERGE` statement together with an `INSERT/UPDATE` and you would have to disable foreign keys for that, since an `UPDATE` is implemented as `DELETE THEN INSERT` (or something like that, don't remember clearly, but I had those problems when I tried).

I prefer doing it this way (SCD type 2 and SQL Server that is):

**Step 1:**

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM sys.objects
WHERE name = 'tmpDimSource')
DROP TABLE tmpDimSource;
SELECT
*
INTO tmpDimSource
FROM
(
SELECT whatever
FROM yourTable
);
```

**Step 2:**

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM sys.objects
WHERE name = 'tmpDimYourDimensionName')
DROP TABLE tmpDimYourDimensionName;

SELECT * INTO tmpDimYourDimensionName FROM D_yourDimensionName WHERE 1 = 0;
INSERT INTO tmpDimYourDimensionName 
(
sid, /*a surrogate id column*/
theColumnsYouNeedInYourDimension,
validFrom
)
SELECT 
ISNULL(d.sid, 0),
ds.theColumnsYouNeedInYourDimension,
DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) /*the current date*/
FROM
tmpDimSource ds 
LEFT JOIN D_yourDimensionName d ON ds.whateverId = c.whateverId
;
```

The `ISNULL(d.sid, 0)` in step 2 is important. It returns the surrogate id of your dimension, if an entry already exists, otherwise 0.

**Step 3:**

```
UPDATE D_yourDimensionName SET 
validTo = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) /*yesterday*/
FROM 
D_yourDimensionName d
INNER JOIN tmpDimYourDimensionName t ON d.sid = t.sid
WHERE t.sid <> 0 AND
(
d.theColumnWhichHasChangedAndIsImportant <> t.theColumnWhichHasChangedAndIsImportant OR
d.anotherColumn <> t.anotherColumn 
)
;
```

In Step 3 you mark the existing entry as not valid anymore and keep a history of it. The valid entry you get with `WHERE validTo IS NULL`.

You can also add another `UPDATE` to overwrite any other column with the new value if needed.

**Step 4:**

```
INSERT INTO D_yourDimensionName 
SELECT * FROM tmpDimYourDimensionName 
WHERE sid = 0;
```

And that's it.

Comment: yes sir through insert update i already know that.. I was wondering if can do something through merge statement..

Comment: Yes, you can, like I said, but you have to disable foreign keys (usually from your facts table if it's a star schema) and it depends on what type of SCD you want to implement. And there is no reasonable way you can write a procedure that can be applied to no matter what tables you throw at it. You can of course write a procedure for every dimension. Feel free.